# How to get the first block of bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I put together a small fork, and I want to extract the first block of bitcoin.

At the moment I can't, and can't understand why, maybe I forgot something to disable or change.

Here is a link to the fork with a modified Genesis blocks. 
I pointed out a time in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to get the first block of bitcoin?

1. take blk0000.dat
2. skip first 8 bytes
3. take 285 bytes

that's all, folks!

Comment: Care to elaborate on that if you are not hard

Comment: Everyone understood what you meant

https://coinlogic.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/the-protocol-1-block/